# How to implement a multi line TextView with max height and internal scroll

Tags: java, android

I want to limit the amount of space a TextView can take in the screen with the following rules:

- If the text is short (lets say 140 characters or 2 lines) let it take as much room as it need  but no more.
- If the text is long, i.e. a paragraph, limit the max height of the view (with some kind of maxHeight or with a maximum number of lines)

Here go some screenshots explaining valid and invalid results:

**Short Text:**

[image]

**Medium Text:**

[image]

**Internal Scroll:**

[image]

**Blank spaces:**

[image]

**Excessive length:**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this.

XML

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/descTxtView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:maxLines="5"
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s."
   android:textColor="#232e3b"
   android:typeface="sans" />
```

in JAVA

```
descTxtView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descTxtView);
descTxtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, why do you use a fixed height of 60dp? I'm testing it with height=wrap_content,maxLines=5 and setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) and seems to work

Comment: my bad use wrap_content

Answer (score 3):

It's easy if you want to limit TextView's height by line, use `android:maxLines`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical" />
```

In your code, write as below:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

With this code, your TextView can be scrolled vertically when the text is longer than the maxLines.